# Convert special characters in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How do I write a bash shell script (under Mac OS X) to convert the names of various files with special characters such as ä, ö, ü? Using sed doesn't work:

```
echo * | sed s/ü/ue/
```

Can I do it some other way?

**EDIT**

Here is the full script. It basically zips up iPhone app packages and then (should) convert any special characters in the zip file name:

```
#/bin/bash

for appfile in *.app
do
    zipfile=`echo ${appfile} | sed s/app/zip/`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/\ /_/`
    # these don't work...
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ä/ae/`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ö/oe/`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ü/ue/`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ß/ss/`
    # make zip
    zip -ruy0 "${zipfile}" "${appfile}"
done
```

**EDIT**

Got it!! The trick is to run the filename through iconv to convert the encoding. I did this before doing the äöü replacements and it worked:

```
zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | iconv -f utf-8-mac -t utf-8`
```

Comment: Spawning `sed` several times in a loop can be expensive. You can combine your substitutions: `sed 's/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/; ...'`. Also, Bash can do them like this: `zipfile=${zipfile//ä/ae/}` (but they have to be done individually).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, although in this case performance is not really an issue. But it's good to know anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `sed /s/ü/ue/g` (note the `g`, *global* replace, so it replaces all occurrences, not just the first occurrence).

Are you trying to rename files? Or just change what the filename looks like for output?

**EDIT**

Try this script:

```
#/bin/bash

for appfile in *.app
do
    zipfile=`echo ${appfile} | sed s/app$/zip/`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/\ /_/g`
    # these don't work...
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ä/ae/g`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ö/oe/g`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ü/ue/g`
    zipfile=`echo ${zipfile} | sed s/ß/ss/g`
    # make zip
    echo zip -ruy0 "${zipfile}" "${appfile}"
done
```

When I run it with two simple filenames, it gives me output like this:

```
$ ./foo.sh
zip -ruy0 ae_oeoe_ue_ss.zip ä  öö ü ß.app
zip -ruy0 ueueueueue.zip üüüüü.app
```

The files are named `ä  öö ü ß.app` and `üüüüü.app`.

I've just placed a `g` at the end of all the `sed` commands, and anchored the `app`. (Which will be nice when you've got one named `appliance.app` or `deliciousapple.app`.) The `echo` at the end is handy for testing. :)

There is something I don't understand: if your filenames have special characters in an iso-8859-1 locale (byte `0xDF` for ß) and your command lines are in UTF-8 (bytes `0xC3 0x9F`), what happens? How about the other way around?

Comment: Basically I'm zipping up various files (individually) and I want to replace the special characters in the name of the zip (not the original files).

Comment: Apparently, under Mac OS X special characters in filenames are stored in "decomposed form", meaning ä is stored as "a" + "COMBINING DIAERESIS" (U+0308). Any idea how I could match for that...?

Comment: Woah, I hadn't known OS X stores (or generates?) filenames so differently than I expected. Could you use `sed s/\x61\x03\x08/ae/g` and so on?

Comment: Found the answer. See my edited question above. Thanks for the app$ and global replace tips though!